# Nissan Presage 98' change tires to 55 profile from 60/65 profile

Tags: tires, nissan

Good day. So we bought a used 98' Nissan Presage (2.5L Turbodiesel/YD25) and we noticed that the tires on the front are 205/65 R16 and the rear left is 215/65 R16 while the rear right is 215/70 R16. We bought the car for cheap and everything seems fine after we've checked it to a mechanic except the tires.

We're gonna replace the tires soon. We've found this firemax tires that costs around cheap Php 2,630 each for a 205/55 R16. Since it has a lower profile than the tires installed,  do you think it is okay to replace the tires with a lower profile 55? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as they clear the wheel wells these should be fine.  Usually just inside the left side door is a sticker from the manufacturer specifying the recommended tire size.

I would think 4 205/55 R16 tires would be MUCH better than the mismatched sizes you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

The factory recommended tire sizes for you car are 215/60R16 or 215/65R16.

201/55R16 tires are smaller in diameter and will give you a reading on the speedometer that is 8% too high compared to 215/65R16 tires. However changing to these tires all-around sounds like a better deal then driving with a mish-mash of sizes like you do now.